# Pushouts of injective monoid homomorphisms

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Given a pushout square in the category of monoids
$$\begin{array}{ccc}A & \rightarrow & M \\ \downarrow && \downarrow \\ N & \rightarrow & P\end{array}$$such that $A \to M$ and $A \to N$ are injective, is it possible to deduce that $M \to P$ and $N \to P$ are injective, too?

The answer is yes if the $A$-actions on $M$ and $N$ are free. In fact, in that case there is even a normal form for the elements of $P$ (Bourbaki, Algebra, Chapter I, §7.3). This happens in particular if $A$ is a group. What happens in the general case? For example, what about $A=(\mathbb{N},+,0)$?

Comment: Does the category of monoids have enough injectives? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: If A is a group but M,N are not the action may not be free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Mark Sapir and Marcel Jackson even showed it is undecidable if the factors embed in an amalgamated free product of finite monoids.

See the intro of [Jackson, Marcel. "The embeddability of ring and semigroup amalgams is undecidable." Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society 69.2 (2000): 272-286.](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700002214)
for an easy example of finite semigroups for which the factors don't embed and add identities.

See also [Sapir, Mark V. "Algorithmic problems for amalgams of finite semigroups." Journal of Algebra 229.2 (2000): 514-531.](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1999.8138).